# Solr: Find words count for 'text' field of an indexed pdf document

Tags: pdf, field, solr4, word-frequency

I am trying to find the *most frequent words in the **text field of an indexed document*** using **Solr 4.10**. I created a PDF document from a text file with some text and posted it to Solr using post.jar and when queried based on its id it gives me pdf contents which are shown below and all  meta-data of the document.

```
<arr name="text">
    <str>sample1</str>
    <str/>
    <str>application/pdf</str>
    <str>
    sample1 sample1.txt cook cook1 book1 book1 book2 nook1 nook1 nook2 nook2 two three four Page 1
    </str>
</arr>
```

In summary I want to detect that we have cook, cook1 with count 1 each and book1,book2,nook1, nook2 with count 2 each.

I used TermVectorComponent configuration from [TermVectorComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent/%22here%22) and my **schema.xml** has the text field:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

and **solrconfig.xml** has

```
<searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

The field type 'text_general' is defined as:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_general" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Finally when I query it from browser using following query which I think is requesting the word count in the 'text' field of the document with id provided i.e.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=id:7e75017b-066d-4257-af10-b770726c7cf4&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&qt=tvrh&tv=true&tv.fl=text&f.text.tv.tf=true&tv.fl=text
```

it returns me all information of the document [**response**](http://www.wikiupload.com/RYPGATW0M15T15B) except the word count. I only want to see the word count in the 'text' field just like the response we obtain when we use rows=0 for faceting i.e. an string array of word vs count.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am trying to get word frequency of 'text' field of one document not of 'text' field of all indexed documents. In other words, how to ask Solr to avoid throwing away duplicate tokens or duplicate stemmed tokens so we can search for most frequent words in a field.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the terms component for this. If you are tokenizing the text field, you should be able to easily facet on the field like so :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=id:7e75017b-066d-4257-af10-b770726c7cf4&facet=true&facet.field=text&facet.mincount=1
```

This will give you a list of tokens (words) in that text field sorted by frequency of occurrence. You can also tweak the facet parameters to suit your needs with facet.limit and etc...

Keep in mind that this will count the tokens in that field, so make sure you review field analyzers/filters to make sure you are getting the correct results since different filters will generate tokens differently.

For exact word count, tokenization on whitespace plus basic stemming will probably get you where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already used faceting and the reply I get looks like [this](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00128292210185953995). You can see that the count shown in this response xml for book1 is 1 even though book1 appears 2 times in the text field.

Comment: I am not doing any tokenization or stemming. How can I do that on text field to get desired result?

Comment: Hmm, please provide field processing for text_general as well as solr output containing the document.

Comment: Here is the text_general: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=48033455931782661698

The output of faceting you can find on this link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00128292210185953995

Comment: I want to see the document in Solr, run the same query, but change rows parameter to 1

Comment: It would also help if you included this information by editing your post instead.

Comment: I edited the question and inserted the text_general in there. The response is too big to put in question so you can find the complete response [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05162786652889362988).

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong with you set-up, but I can positively say that this works because I use it. I would suggest you use a dev environment with some artificial data to get the process working right. Then you can transition to using your data. That way you will know if the problem is with the data or your set-up.